# Getting Check Constraint error when trying to insert into a table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

We are in the process of putting a partnering site on our ERP system.  They have a notes table that I am trying to move into our notes table by scripting it in T-SQL since there are hundreds of records.  I am using SQL Server 2008R2.  I keep getting an The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "ObjectNotesCk4". The conflict occurred in database "PLT_NAMALT_App", table "dbo.ObjectNotes" error.

Some details.  Our ObjectNotes table requires the RowPointer from the PO, the PK from the SpecificNotes table and then some additional fields which I'm populating with constants.  So first I capture the RowPointer from the PO table using a cursor, then I insert into the SpecificNotes table matching on PO#  and try to capture the PK using OUTPUT INTO a temp table.  Then I try to insert into the ObjectNotes table using the variable I inserted into in my OUTPUT.  So my query...(just an FYI I am limiting it to one PO#, one line # for verification).

```
DECLARE @SpecificToken TABLE (SpecificTokenID TokenType, NoteContent OleObjectType, NoteDesc LongDescType)

DECLARE @RowPointer RowPointerType

DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR 
  LOCAL STATIC FOR 

SELECT  RowPointer FROM poitem

OPEN MY_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @RowPointer 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO SpecificNotes  (NoteContent, NoteDesc)
        OUTPUT inserted.SpecificNoteToken, inserted.NoteContent, inserted.NoteDesc
        INTO @SpecificToken
    SELECT LongNote, 'Visual Note'
    FROM purc_line_notes vb 
    JOIN  poline slp
    ON vb.PONUM = slp.po_num
    and vb.LINE_NO = po_line
    WHERE slp.po_num = 'P000060883'
    and slp.po_line = '1'
    AND slp.rowpointer = @RowPointer

    INSERT INTO ObjectNotes (RefRowPointer,NoteHeaderToken,SpecificNoteToken,NoteType)
    VALUES (@OuterID, 5, (SELECT SpecificTokenID FROM @SpecificToken),0)

    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @RowPointer 
END
CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
```

Also when testing what the values are in @SpecificToken, SpecificNoteToken is 0 but should be 185 (checked the value in the SpecificNotes table)

In SpecificNotes, SpecificNoteToken is the Primary Key, which is why I do my insert into that table first.
In ObjectNotes, ObjectNoteToken is the Primary Key but SpecificNoteToken is a foreign key.  RefRowPointer is a foreign key to the poline table (slp).

This is my first time using OUTPUT INTO, I'm not sure this is the right way to go since I am reading mixed things about being able to use it with a primary key.  I also apologize for being wordy, I wanted to make sure I described my situation thoroughly.

Comment: What is the definition of the constraint?

Comment: Try running: `SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('ObjectNotesCk4'))`

Comment: (NOT [SystemNoteToken] IS NULL OR NOT [UserNoteToken] IS NULL OR NOT [SpecificNoteToken] IS NULL).  The UserNotes table is completely empty and so is SpecificNotes.

Comment: Do you have any triggers on the `SpecificNotes` table? What is the data type for the `SpecificTokenID` column (the base type of `TokenType`)? Is there a default value for this column?